# Regex: Matching ',' after zero or odd occurrences of a double quote

Tags: php, regex, csv, dfa

I am attempting to pull apart a row from a CSV file without using a parser and all I need to do is split the string based on the commas using php. In itself this is fairly easy if you have no commas in the input, which isn't the case. I want to ignore the commas that are encapsulated in double quotes.

Completely ignoring the last sentence, I decided to change the problem itself to the following:

I want to split the string based on commas that are preceded by no double quotes or scattered pairs of double quotes.

Example:

```
text,"some,"chars,chars"more,""text",
    *     x      *          x       *
```

Where * are matches and x is not.

Is this beyond the ability of a regex, and if not, is there a regular expression that can process this kind of input?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use str_getcsv() http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php ? Incidentally, your example string would be invalid as " within " should be escaped, or you have blobs such as "some,"chars that aren't properly quoted when they should be

Comment: I'm sure it can be done, but it's probably easier to use something like `fgetcsv()` to do the parsing for you.

Comment: Can be done. In fact I have one, but it does conform more to standard CSV rules, not your escaping variant and in-value mixed quoted/unquoted string parts.

Comment: parsing CSV is way harder than it might seem. This is one of those times when a regex can't cut the mustard. Use a real CSV parsing lib.

Comment: Can't be done. Despite your coloring scheme, the comma in "chars,chars" is still enclosed in quotes :)

Comment: Your example can't be from a CSV file as it's not valid CSV

Comment: Don't you want to find commas preceded by an *even* number of double quotes?  For example, both commas in `zero,"one",two`?

Comment: @KeithThompson: That's what the example seems to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this can be written much nicer, but here is a variant that works for your case:

```
 preg_match_all('/
     \s* ((?: (?=.|(?<=,)$) [^",]* | "(?: ""|[^"]* )+" )+) \s* (?:,|$) /xms',
     $line, $matches
 )
 and print_r($matches[1]);
```

But it doesn't honor other typical CSV rules. I would normally expect `\"` to be the escaped double quotes within. And the mixed quoted and unquoted substrings are also very unstandard. And it lacks any form of validation, so will just overlook any last quote-whatever if not correctly paired.

For your test string:

```
        [0] => text
        [1] => "some,"chars
        [2] => chars"more,""text"
        [3] =>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your CSV file is correct (each field either begins and ends with a " or does not contain a ", then you could parse the string with a recursive function, like so:

```
$csvString = 'zero,"o,ne",two,"thr,ee"';

function parseCsv($string, &$result)
{
    $regex = '/^((".*")|([^"].*))(,(.*))?$/U';
    $matches = array();
    preg_match($regex, $string, $matches);
    $result[] = $matches[1];
    if(isset($matches[5]))
    {
        parseCsv($matches[5], $result);
    }
}

$result = array();
parseCsv($csvString, $result);

var_dump($result);
```

Note that this has not been tested with quoted strings that contain (escaped) quotes. Also it keeps the quotes around quoted strings.

The result of the above function is

```
array
  0 => string 'zero' (length=4)
  1 => string '"o,ne"' (length=6)
  2 => string 'two' (length=3)
  3 => string '"thr,ee"' (length=8)
```